# Trying to convert the character encoding in a dataset

Tags: r

I would like to convert the character encoding of one of my variable in a dataset but I don't understand why the iconv command is not working.

My gist file is here : https://gist.github.com/pachevalier/5850660

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ideas come to mind:
1) you have a simple problem and are asking the wrong question

-- the final line in your Gist is
    `Encoding(tab$fiche_communale$Nom)`
Are you actually wanting:
    `Encoding(tab$fiche_communale$name)`

2) `readHTMLTable` may not be reading in the character encoding correctly, in which case, you could set it explicitly with `Encoding(tab$fiche_communale$Nom) <- "latin-1"`

3) try relying on `iconv` to detect the local encoding:
    `iconv(tab$fiche_communale$Nom, from="", to="UTF-8")`

Comment: The first point is right but doesn't solve my problem. The output of tab$fiche_communale$name is still not as it should be.

Comment: Funny, when I grabbed the text of the website and pasted it into Textmate, and then into R, I ended up with "latin1", and `iconv` worked fine. When I installed the XML package and used the readHTMLTable command, it didn't work unless I had `iconv` interpret the locale itself by passing an empty string.

Comment: The third solution is the good one. I didn't knew that we could pass an empty argument to iconv(). Thank you very much.